# PHP CURL syntax for WIX

Tags: php, curl, velo

I'm using Wix's API to query products. I've made progress converting their examples to PHP but am stumped with their filtering method. For example, this basic query:

```
    curl -X POST \
   'https://www.wixapis.com/stores/v1/products/query' \
    --data-binary '{
                     "includeVariants": true
                   }' \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -H 'Authorization: <AUTH>'enter code here
```

works fine when rewritten as:

```
public function getProducts($code){
    $curl_postData = array(
        'includeVariants' => 'true'
    );
    $params = json_encode($curl_postData);
    $productsURL = 'https://www.wixapis.com/stores/v1/products/query';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $productsURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $headers = [
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:' . $code
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlErr = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

But I'm having trouble filtering to a specific collection. Here's their example:

```
curl 'https://www.wixapis.com/stores/v1/products/query' \
--data-binary '{
                 "query": {
                   "filter": "{\"collections.id\": { \"$hasSome\": [\"32fd0b3a-2d38-2235-7754-78a3f819274a\"]} }"
                 }
               }' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: <AUTH>'
```

And here's my interpretation of it (*$collection* is my variable to replace the fixed value in Wix's example):

```
public function getProducts($code, $collection){
    $curl_postData = array(
        'filter' => array(
            'collections.id' => array(
                '$hasSome' => $collection
            )
        )
    );
    $params = json_encode($curl_postData);
    $productsURL = 'https://www.wixapis.com/stores/v1/products/query';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $productsURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $headers = [
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:' . $code
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlErr = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

The response is identical to the first example--I get all the products instead of just one collection. The problem is almost certainly my interpretation of their example. I *think* it's meant to be a multidimensional array, but I could be reading it wrong. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You're not sending `$params` in either code block. It should be `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);`

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the solution. Apparently I deleted params in one of my testing of variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code block, the value of the `filter` property is not an object, but a JSON-encoded object. I'm not sure why the API requires that, but it means you have to use nested `json_encode()` in PHP.

```
    $curl_postData = array(
        'filter' => json_encode(array(
            'collections.id' => array(
                '$hasSome' => $collection
            )
        ))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Barmar. Your answer was correct with a minor change. Here's the final code segment that works properly.

```
$curl_postData = array(
    'query' => array(
        'filter' => json_encode(array(
            'collections.id' => array(
                '$hasSome' => $collection
            )
        ))
    )
);
```

Comment: You should accept this answer since it's more correct than mine.